# Vuetify error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use vuetify now, but i am really confused on how to use it. I have used CDN, and copy-pasted the html and javascript code from vuetify.js, but it doesn't work at all. It returned error `uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export.`
This is the html code:

```
<template>
  <v-card height="200px">
    <v-bottom-nav
      absolute
      shift
      value="true"
      :class="{
        'blue-grey': e2 === 1,
        'teal': e2 === 2,
        'brown': e2 === 3,
        'brown lighten-1': e2 === 4
      }"
    >
      <v-btn dark @click.native="e2 = 1" :value="e2 === 1">
        <span>Video</span>
        <v-icon>ondemand_video</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn dark @click.native="e2 = 2" :value="e2 === 2">
        <span>Music</span>
        <v-icon>music_note</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn dark @click.native="e2 = 3" :value="e2 === 3">
        <span>Book</span>
        <v-icon>book</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn dark @click.native="e2 = 4" :value="e2 === 4">
        <span>Image</span>
        <v-icon>image</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-bottom-nav>
  </v-card>
</template>

and javascript code:
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        e2: 3
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you say you have copy&pasted that code - where have you pasted it to? This is a single file component, which requires a build setup with webpack&vue-loader to be turned into a javascript version which the browser can understand...

Comment: actually i dont know how to work with vuetify. I assumed that vuetify and materialize/bootstrap can be used in the same way. I only made a html file then copy-paste CDN, its js and html code into this html file. Can u help me how to use vuetify? @LinusBorg

Answer (score 2):

Vuetify now has a CDN quick-start at https://vuetifyjs.com/vuetify/quick-start. I recommend setting that up and then you should be able to copy and paste code from the documentation examples.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I rerun `npm run serve` and refreshed the browser before the Vuetify default page loaded with no errors